# Error opening terminal: unknown when executing nano

Tags: centos, ssh, nano

I have nano installed on a CentOS 7 VPS. When trying to open a file using nano, such as `sudo nano /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf`, i get `Error opening terminal: unknown.` I am using Termius to access my VPS using SSH

Comment: @RobertLongson yes it does actually! What does that export do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to set the TERM environment variable. That tells nano how to run within the Termius environment i.e. it encodes what capabilities Termius has.

```
export TERM="xterm"
```

Should work for you, although you could also try export `TERM="xterm-256color"` or [experiment with other values from terminfo](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/terminfo.5.html).

Add this line to ~/.profile (you might have to create that file) if you want to avoid having to run it every time you log in and want to use nano.